Using the <template> vs <div> for conditional rendering
The Salesforce documentation states that lwc:if tags can be used with  or  or really any HTML tags.
Is there a significant difference in functionality between adding a <template> vs a <div> tag to render its subcomponents conditionally?

Personally I make the choice of using <template> or a tag that renders in the HTML e.g. <div> based on readability.
If your HTML is carefully indented, adding <template> tags messes that indenting up (assuming you are thinking about the rendered HTML structure). But that is sometimes OK e.g. to break up large blocks of markup. It's also arguably a hangover from earlier conditional rendering frameworks.
Adding the tags to e.g. a <div> preserves the indenting at the cost of mixing up the HTML markup with the conditional logic. But this often reads more clearly. It's turning the element itself on or off rather than wrapping the element in an on or off switch using a weird non-rendering tag.
Using a <div> to just contain the on or off logic is an anti-pattern IMO: use a <template> tag to avoid the pointless extra <div> in the output.
My assumption is that there is no significant difference in behavior or performance between the two approaches.

Historically, there was a point when you had to use template for conditional rendering, because other tags might render incorrectly due to a bug. Further, there was a point where there were two conflicting statements in HTML Template Directives and Render DOM Elements Conditionally, at which point I reached out to the documentation team, who researched the topic and updated the documentation to match expected behavior (usable on any element). The bugs I found with conditional rendering had also been ironed out by that point.
There is very little technical difference between using lwc:if on either a <template> or a <div> (or literally anything you want, like a span or even a custom component). That means it's more a matter of personal preference in most cases. However, keep in mind that using a <div> over a <template> might change the layout of the page, such that you'll also need to deal with related CSS that may change as a result.
Personally, I choose to live by a "less is more" approach to coding. If something you want to render is just text, a <template> can be appropriate. Further, if you want to Render Lists, you need to use a <template>, so you can have the <template> do double duty by making the list dynamically rendered in one element instead of two.
Otherwise, if you already naturally have a <div> or any other element that should be conditionally rendered, you can save some lines of code by skipping the <template>. This can be helpful in situations where your templates are running up against the 131,072 character limit of any LWC file in Salesforce, or just to improve legibility where a single blank line can delineate different blocks in your template.
